# Unity FileNotFoundException "launcherTemplate.gradle" when building for Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When using Unity 2021.3.6f1 I get a an error saying `launcherTemplate.gradle` file cannot be found. I don't see it referenced in the project anywhere.

I tried using a custom gradle file, modify existing gradle files but nothing has done the trick so far.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpHvP.png)

```
FileNotFoundException: Failed to find $E:/Unity Game Engine/2021.3.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\GradleTemplates\baseProjectTemplate.gradle
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.GetTemplate (System.String toolsPath, System.String fileName) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor+<GetDataForBuildProgramFor>d__21.MoveNext () (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.SetupBeeDriver (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue after upgrading to 2021.3.6f1. I've contacted support to see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related to Unity Hub not installing Android build tooling properly.

From https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-build-quest-game.1307529/

> Unity Hub installer neglects to install the tools directory to this path:
> c:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.6f1\Editor\Data\Tools\
>
> Copying over the directory from another recent Unity Editor installation will allow one to make Quest/Android builds again.